# Sugerencias del routing en mi web con MVC

Tags: javascript, php, mvc, vscode

Acabo de hacer el deployment de mi pagina web con docker en mi instancia de ec2, al momento de subirlo todos los enlaces de mi web me llevan al inicio pero en la barra me aparece bien el routing. Que puede ser? O que tengo que configurar? Pd. El .htaccess no tiene ningun problema